# How to distinguish two states with same density matrix using a quantum state tomography?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement, state-tomography

I tried to measure quantum state with a quantum state tomography. However, I encountered a situation when two different quantum states had the same density matrix. In particular, these states were $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle + \frac{1+i}{2}|1\rangle$ and $\frac{1-i}{2}|0\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle$.

**My question is:** Is there any possibility how to distinguish these two states (or any other two states with the same density matrix) with quantum state tomography?

Comment: Both of those states are same, they only differ by a global phase!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't. A density matrix encodes all the knowledge available about a state, therefore if two states are described by the same density matrix, they are indistinguishable.

Ket vectors differing by only a global phase have always the same density matrix, and represent the same physical state.

Comment: Right, that.   I wrote a similar answer in parallel.  :-)

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The question presupposes a misconception that the vector form of a state $|\psi\rangle$ exists independently of its density operator form $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$, which is often described as secondary.  In reality, the density operator of a state is all that truly exists --- and even then, it only exists as statistical information.  In fact, you can construct quantum mechanics using density operators $\rho$ as the primary model of states.  The formalism for this is similar to the Heisenberg picture of quantum mechanics, in which operators evolve over time.  In a Heisenberg-type picture, you don't strictly need Hilbert spaces at all at first, you can define everything with abstract "operators".  You can introduce a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ later as an algebra representation of all of the operators.  You can also introduce vector states $|\psi\rangle$ later as a simplified formalism for operator states that happen to have the form $\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$.